# Responsive Grid-layout: Img height scales different on smaller viewport sizes

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I'm making a new site based on bootstrap: [Link](http://stef.webnuts.io/). The homepage contains a grid system with a lot of uneven columns. See picture below:

[image: Grid with uneven columns containing imgs with text overlay]

The problem ist that on different viewport width the height of the images gets scaled down different. See second image below...

[image: Height scales different on smaller viewport sizes]

How can I solve this problem? I want all imgs at all time to keep the same height so the margins between the rows stay the same.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it according to the example found here.

See example. http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/dPzpBd

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="item large h2">40%</div>
<div class="item small h2">25%</div>
<div class="item medium">35%</div>
<div class="item medium h2">35%</div>
<div class="item small">25%</div>
<div class="item large">40%</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.grid-sizer { width: 5%; }

.item {
float: left;
background: #D10;
height: 100px;
border-right: 2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
font-size: 36px;
color: white;
}
.item.small { width: 25%; }
.item.medium { width: 35%; }
.item.large { width: 40%; }
.item.h2 { height: 150px; }
```

JS

```
$('.grid').masonry({
itemSelector: '.item',
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have one `row` per 12 `cols`.

Right now you have way too many columns in a single row.

Follow the structure of `container` > `row` > `col`.